# How to show errors each input fields using nodejs with express-validator?

Tags: node.js, validation, express, express-validator

This question already asked but that not solve my issue.

Am new in `Nodejs`. I tried to validate form while inserting data.

Here am using `express-validator`, error messages showing top of the `form`.

This my error message:

[image]

But i want it show under each input fields

This is my code

**.pug:**

```
form(action="/admin/add_employee", method="POST")
    .form-group
        label.col-form-label First Name
        input.form-control(type="text", name="first_name", placeholder="Enter employee first name")
        div(style='color:red') #{errFirstName}
    .form-group
        label.col-form-label Last Name
        input.form-control(type="text", name="last_name", placeholder="Enter employee last name")
        div(style='color:red') #{errLastName}
    .form-group
        label.col-form-label Email
        input.form-control(type="email", name="email", placeholder="Enter employee email id")
    .form-group
        label.col-form-label Phone
        input.form-control(type="text", name="phone", placeholder="Enter employee phone")
    .form-group
        label.col-form-label Address
        textarea.form-control(type="text", name="address", placeholder="Enter employee address")
    input.btn.btn-primary(type="submit", name="save", value="Save Employee")
```

**.js:**

```
router.post('/add_employee', function(req, res){
    const first_name = req.body.first_name;
    const last_name = req.body.last_name;
    const email = req.body.email;
    const phone = req.body.phone;
    const address = req.body.address;

    req.checkBody('first_name', 'Please enter employee first name').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('last_name', 'Please enter employee last name').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email', 'Please enter employee email').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email', 'Invalid Email id').isEmail();
    req.checkBody('phone', 'Please enter employee phone').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('address', 'Please enter employee address').notEmpty();

    let errors = req.validationErrors();

    if(errors)
    {
        res.render('emp_add', {
            errors: errors
        });
    }
    else
    {
        let employee_data = Employee();
        employee_data.first_name = first_name;
        employee_data.fast_name = last_name;
        employee_data.email = email;
        employee_data.phone = phone;
        employee_data.address = address;
        employee_data.status = 1;

        console.log(employee_data);
        employee_data.save(function(err){
            if(err)
            {
                console.log(err);
                return;
            }
            else
            {

                req.flash('success', 'Employee added successfully');
                res.redirect('employee_list');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

> I want to show error message under the text box

Answer (score 0):

The error you get on validation is an array.

For the first error message use -

```
errors[0].msg
```

One suggestion though you can use the following library to add validations on front end as well - [Library](https://jqueryvalidation.org/)
This library is customisable and awesome.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function on the server side to loop through your errors and returns an object with the name of the field as the key and the error as the value.

```
for (let i=0; i<errors.errors.length; i++) {
    newErrors[errors.errors[i].param] = errors.errors[i].msg
}
```

Then you can show the error in a p tag or the like with `this.state.errors.username` or password or whatever you called it when sending it to the server side.